# Javascript problem while converting into django template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, css, django

I'm struggling with a conversion of a html file into a django template. It seems like the `main.js` file is not working but debug console doesn't throw any errors.

I have just copied the files from my local filesystem onto my webserver and changed the url of the static files. There are no 404 errors.

This is how my html document looks like on the local file system:

> [image: HTML navigation on file system]

This is how the templated version on the web server looks like:

> [image: HTML navigation on the webserver]

This my include order of the javascript files:

```
<script  src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}" ></script>
[...]
<script  src="{% static "js/main.js" %}" ></script>
```

Comment: The quoting is wrong.  You can't nest double quotes inside double quotes. Use `src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon that is just false. The quotes are in different contexts. Using double quotes for both is fine.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the css file. I had an old file from another template with the same name in my static path.

Deleting style.css and rerunning 
python manage.py collectstatic solved the problem.